# Reading in a time with fractional seconds and AM/PM

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

This is probably a really basic question, but how do I read a datetime with fractional seconds *and* an AM/PM indicator into R?

```
> x <- "2014/10/20 3:00:49.324 PM"

> as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-10-20 03:00:49 MYT"                   # wrong; should be 15:00:49

> as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-10-20 03:00:49 MYT"                   # wrong; should be 15:00:49

> as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p")
[1] NA

> as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] NA
```

If I change it to 24-hour format, there's no problem, and ditto if I remove the fractional seconds.

```
> x <- "2014/10/20 15:00:49.324"
> as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-10-20 15:00:49 MYT"

> x <- "2014/10/20 3:00:49 PM"
> as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2014-10-20 15:00:49 MYT"
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%OS %p")`?

Comment: And with `lubridate::ymd_hms(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fractional seconds use `%OS` format (it isn't well documented, but it *is* one of the examples in `?strptime`). You should also remember to use `%I` (instead of `%H`) when combined with `%p`. Also, don't forget to set `tz` if needed.

```
as.POSIXct("2014/10/20 3:00:49.324 PM", format = "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%OS %p")
## "2014-10-20 15:00:49 IDT"
```